# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

Given `t.id`, `a.id`, `t1.name` and `t2.name`, how do I add or update `t1_has_t2.data`?

I can update it if there is currently a record.

```
UPDATE t1_has_t2
INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.id=t1_has_t2.t1_id
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id=t1_has_t2.t2_id
SET t1_has_t2.data=123
WHERE t1.name="foo" AND t1.t_id=333 AND t2.name="bar" AND t2.t_id=333;
```

How can I insert it if a record currently doesn't exist?

EDIT.  Would it be something like the following?  Seems a waste to include `t` in the JOIN.

```
INSERT INTO t1_has_t2(t1_id,t2_id,data)
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, 123
FROM t
INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.t_id=t.id
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t_id=t.id
WHERE t1.name="foo" AND t1.t_id=333 AND t2.name="bar" AND t2.t_id=333
ON DUPLICATE KEY SET t1_has_t2.data=123;
```

EDIT2.  Ah, maybe I get it now.  I just JOIN t1 and t2 to each other through their shared t.id?

```
INSERT INTO t1_has_t2(t1_id,t2_id,data)
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, 123
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t_id=t1.t_id
WHERE t1.name="foo" AND t1.t_id=333 AND t2.name="bar" AND t2.t_id=333
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE t1_has_t2.data=123;
```

[image]

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 08/08/16 07:40:04
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`accounts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`accounts` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`t` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accounts_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `accounts_id`),
  INDEX `fk_t_accounts_idx` (`accounts_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t_accounts`
    FOREIGN KEY (`accounts_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`accounts` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`t1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`t1` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `t_accounts_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_t1_t1_idx` (`t_id` ASC, `t_accounts_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `un1` (`t_id` ASC, `name` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t1_t1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`t_id` , `t_accounts_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`t` (`id` , `accounts_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`t2`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`t2` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `t_accounts_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_t2_t1_idx` (`t_id` ASC, `t_accounts_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `un2` (`t_id` ASC, `name` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t2_t1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`t_id` , `t_accounts_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`t` (`id` , `accounts_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`t1_has_t2`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`t1_has_t2` (
  `t1_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `t2_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `data` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t1_id`, `t2_id`),
  INDEX `fk_t1_has_t2_t21_idx` (`t2_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_t1_has_t2_t11_idx` (`t1_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t1_has_t2_t11`
    FOREIGN KEY (`t1_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`t1` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_t1_has_t2_t21`
    FOREIGN KEY (`t2_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`t2` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Might be better to ask this in the DB Administrator stream http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @alsobubbly  Never really sure where to post questions like this one.  Both sites seem appropriate.

Comment: No problem but thought you might be get a better response there, no harm in asking it here though

Answer (score 0):

Works fine if I understand what you want with [Insert on Duplicate Key Update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) (IODKU).

Data Load:

```
insert accounts(id) values (NULL); -- id = 1
insert t(accounts_id) values (1); -- id = 1

insert t1(t_id,t_accounts_id,name) values (1,1,'n1'); -- id=1
insert t1(t_id,t_accounts_id,name) values (1,1,'n2'); -- id=2
insert t2(t_id,t_accounts_id,name) values (1,1,'n1'); -- id=1   
insert t2(t_id,t_accounts_id,name) values (1,1,'n2'); -- id=2

insert t1_has_t2(t1_id,t2_id,data) values(1,1,'one_one'); -- success
insert t1_has_t2(t1_id,t2_id,data) values(1,77,'x'); -- Error 1452 as expected
insert t1_has_t2(t1_id,t2_id,data) values(77,1,'x'); -- Error 1452 as expected
insert t1_has_t2(t1_id,t2_id,data) values(1,2,'one_two'); -- success
insert t1_has_t2(t1_id,t2_id,data) values(2,1,'two_one'); -- success
insert t1_has_t2(t1_id,t2_id,data) values(2,2,'two_two'); -- success
```

Your Query:

```
UPDATE t1_has_t2
INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.id=t1_has_t2.t1_id
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id=t1_has_t2.t2_id
SET t1_has_t2.data='I am a string'
WHERE t1.name="n1" AND t1.t_id=1 AND t2.name="n1" AND t2.t_id=1;
```

IODKU:

```
insert t1_has_t2(t1_id,t2_id,data) values(2,2,'two_two_version002')
on duplicate key update data='anchovies';
```

See results:

```
select * from t1_has_t2;
+-------+-------+---------------+
| t1_id | t2_id | data          |
+-------+-------+---------------+
|     1 |     1 | I am a string |
|     1 |     2 | one_two       |
|     2 |     1 | two_one       |
|     2 |     2 | anchovies     |
+-------+-------+---------------+
```

You can also look into

```
insert ignore t1_has_t2(t1_id,t2_id,data) [something];
```

Which succeeds or fails silently by design.

Comment: for your IODKU query, you don't have the values of t1_id and t2_id unless you do a couple previous queries which I don't wish to do.

Comment: how about mapping out what you would like to insert, and what you would like to update (based on what condition). You certainly haven't done that for the INSERT side, unless you are saying you want 1 row to go in ?

Comment: I think my EDIT2 query works.  Given `t.id` of 333, `t1.name` of "foo", and `t2.name` of "bar", insert a record in `t1_has_t2` with `data` of 123 and the primary keys of the other two tables, but only update `data` if it already exists for those two primary keys.